# how to escape carriage return but skip already escaped character in java

Tags: java, regex

here's the input string:

```
"\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\ram\\Microsoft\\19.070.0410.0007\remoteAccess.dll\""
```

i'd like to escape '\r' for remoteAccess but leave one in \ram alone, so the result should look like the following:

```
"\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\ram\\Microsoft\\19.070.0410.0007\\remoteAccess.dll\""
```

I tried `StringEscapeUtils` but it just escapes everything. Negative lookbehind doesn't seem to work in java:

```
String sub = resp.replaceAll("(?<!\\)\\r", "\\\\r");
```

produces

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 8
(?<!\)\r
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That is text in a entered in a text file or on the keyboard, not java source code where "\r" would be the cariagge return and "\"" the double quote?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the normal String `\` is escaped as `\\` and in regex
an escaped backslash must be written as `\\\\`. If you then have *two* escaped backslashes ...

```
    // String as in java source: \\ is actualy a \, \" actually a ".
    String resp = "\"\\\"C:\\\\Users\\\\Administrator\\\\ram\\\\Microsoft\\\\"
            + "19.070.0410.0007\\remoteAccess.dll\\\"\"";
    System.out.println(resp); // The input as you did show.

    // Regex solution:
    String sub = resp.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\r", "\\\\\\\\r");
    String sub = resp.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\\\(\\w)", "\\\\\\\\$1");
    System.out.println(sub);

    // Simple string replace:
    String sub2 = resp.replace("\\\\", "\\").replace("\\", "\\\\");
    sub2 = sub2.replace("\\\\\"", "\\\""); // Undo for \"
    System.out.println(sub2);
```

The non-regex simple string `replace` seems clearest. Both solutions do not count the consecutive backslashes, and whether it is odd or even makes a difference.
But the non-regex version is safer, as it replaces, and then continues *after* the replacement.